# Pip chosing requirements version

Tags: python, installation, pip, version

I am asking myself, which version of the library *pip* will install in this scenario:

`requirements.txt` contains:

```
numpy<=1.14
scikit-learn
```

Now imagine, that `scikit-learn` depends on `numpy>=1.10`.
If I start `pip install -r requirements.txt` now, how will pip install the dependencies?

1. Does it **parse the whole dependency structure *before* installing** and finds a valid version of numpy?
2. Does it just parse the file and dependencies sequentially (package by package) and tries to go for the best "last" dependency?

In my example this would be:

1. `numpy==1.14`
2. `numpy==latest`

The essential question is: In which order will pip install its dependencies? How does it determine the proper version, respecting all cross dependencies?

**EDIT:** My initial guess would be, that it has an internal list with valid version and cancels out invalid versions by parsing all dependencies before installing. Then it takes the highest valid remaining version of each package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to know: Most likely the order will change soon. *pip* is currently (today: September 2020) slowly rolling out a new *dependency resolver*. It can be used today already but is not the default. So depending which dependency resolver you are using, results might differ.

A couple of pointers:

- [*pip*'s documentation chapter "*Installation Order*"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#installation-order)
- [*pip*'s documentation chapter "Changes to the pip dependency resolver in 20.2 (2020)"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-2-2020)